# VBA range delete script

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with this table, and I need to write a script that recognizes the word carrots: and deletes one row above it and 7 row below it, including the actual row.

I've tried multiple approaches but all of them are failing me for some reason, so I guess I'm missing something minor.

```
Sub delete()
startRow = 19
Set dataSheet = Sheets(1)

 endRow = dataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 Dim horse

  horse = Range(i - 1, i + 7)

For i = startRow To endRow
If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "Entity:" Then
Cells(horse, "A").EntireRow.delete

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I also tried, going cells(i-1,A).. Plus one to seven etc. Not working. looking for tips?

Comment: You've got to go from the last row to the first otherwise you'll end up with weird results when you delete your row and then iterate to the next one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

When deleting rows or columns it best to loop backwards.

Your `horse` line was outside the loop so `i` had no value.

You declare and assign a sheet but never use the variable.

Also it is good practice to declare all variables.

```
Sub delete()
Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long
Dim i as Long
startRow = 19
Set datasheet = Sheets(1)

endRow = datasheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
With datasheet
    For i = endRow To startRow Step -1
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "Entity:" Then
            .Rows(i - 1 & ":" & i + 7).delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How does your range improvement show you going back words? It seems like you're still going from top to bottom with the - 1

Comment: @Matty no it is now stepping -1 as it starts at the higher number endow and then steps -1 till it gets to the lower number startrow.